# MySQL - Prepared Statement and String Introducer

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

**Does a prepared statement ignore string introducers?**

I did the following test and it seems that this is the case. Am i missing something?

```
/*Setting the variables*/
SET @str1 = _utf8mb4'some text' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
SET @str2 = _utf16'some text' COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci;
SET @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = 'cp1250';
SET @@CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION = 'ucs2';
SET @@COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'ucs2_unicode_ci';
SET @@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = 'ascii';

/*Preparing the prepared statement*/
PREPARE showStringInfo FROM 'SELECT
                               ?            `Input`,
                               CHARSET(?)   `Input Character Set`,
                               COLLATION(?) `Input Collation`,
                               @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT,
                               @@CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION,
                               @@COLLATION_CONNECTION,
                               @@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;';
```

Executing

```
EXECUTE showStringInfo
USING @str1, @str1, @str1;
```

Results in

```
| some text | ucs2 | ucs2_unicode_ci | cp1250 | ucs2 | ucs2_unicode_ci | ascii
```

And executing

```
EXECUTE showStringInfo
USING @str2, @str2, @str2;
```

Results in

```
 s???? | ucs2 | ucs2_unicode_ci | cp1250 | ucs2 | ucs2_unicode_ci | ascii
```

While querying

```
SELECT
  @str1            `Input`,
  CHARSET(@str1)   `Input Character Set`,
  COLLATION(@str1) `Input Collation`,
  @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT,
  @@CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION,
  @@COLLATION_CONNECTION,
  @@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
```

Results in

```
some text | utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_bin | cp1250 | ucs2 | ucs2_unicode_ci | ascii
```

And querying

```
SELECT
  @str2            `Input`,
  CHARSET(@str2)   `Input Character Set`,
  COLLATION(@str2) `Input Collation`,
  @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT,
  @@CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION,
  @@COLLATION_CONNECTION,
  @@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
```

Results in

```
s???? | utf16 | utf16_unicode_ci | cp1250 | ucs2 | ucs2_unicode_ci | ascii
```

**The test seems to suggest that stored procedures assume @@CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION and @@COLLATION_CONNECTION on strings regardless of the introducer**

(Tested using both DataGrip's JDBC and mysql.exe)

Comment: I tested and it seems to work fine if I use utf8mb4 instead of utf32. Is there any reason you need to use utf32? That will make all your characters take four bytes.

Comment: The choice of character sets was just for testing purposes.
I'll attempt to make an even clearer test to see if the character set is assumed to be one of (@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT, @@CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION, @@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS).